# require in .emacs config file not working

Tags: emacs, prettier

I have installed prettier for emacs using the instructions here: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-emacs. Doing `which prettier` gives me the location of prettier. 
Then I put

`(require 'prettier-js)`

and

```
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'prettier-js-mode)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'prettier-js-mode)
```

in my `~/.emacs` file. I also put prettier-js.el in my `~/` directory. Then I restart emacs and try the command

```
M-x customize-group prettier-js
```

but `prettier-js` is not a `customize-group` option, suggesting that it is not installed. How can I install prettier-js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in my `~/.emacs` file. I also put `prettier-js.el` in my `~/` directory.

This is most likely your problem.  With the exception of `.emacs`, your home directory is not an appropriate place to put elisp libraries.  By default Emacs will not look for them there, and you shouldn't tell it that it's safe to look for them there either.

Make a new directory under your `~/.emacs.d/` directory for elisp libraries.  I suggest: `~/.emacs.d/lisp`

Put `prettier-js.el` in there instead: `~/.emacs.d/lisp/prettier-js.el`

Then in your init file add this line ahead of the `require`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp"))
(require 'prettier-js)
```

Now Emacs will be able to find it (and any other libraries you put in that directory).

You should also byte-compile the `.el` file using `M-x byte-compile-file`